# Hibernate connectio exception

Tags: android, hibernate, c3p0

I am using hibernate as DAL to MySql server.
I had a problem before in connection exception and I moced to use C3P0 connection pools.
Now I got the following exception (after few hours the connection was not in use).
Attached a complete exception log from the server.
It took 3 or 4 request to the server until it worked fine.
This cause a problem in the client - user sees error when should not see it.

Really really need some help

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1198)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4690)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.rollback(NewProxyConnection.java:855)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:192)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 30,799,782 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 174 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3090)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2979)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3520)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2281)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:940)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at com.icdb.ICDBWebService.GetUserFriends(ICDBWebService.java:1981)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2540)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2990)
    ... 48 more
[INFO] Problem with checked-in Statement, discarding.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkClosed(StatementImpl.java:447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.clearParameters(PreparedStatement.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache.refreshStatement(GooGooStatementCache.java:604)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache.checkinStatement(GooGooStatementCache.java:236)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.checkinStatement(NewPooledConnection.java:282)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.close(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1807)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closePreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:563)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:291)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:307)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1967)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:940)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at com.icdb.ICDBWebService.searchUsers(ICDBWebService.java:2209)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
[WARN] [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
[WARN] [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed. ] which will not be reported to listeners!
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1198)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4690)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.rollback(NewProxyConnection.java:855)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:192)
    at com.icdb.ICDBWebService.searchUsers(ICDBWebService.java:2252)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 30,428,851 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3090)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2979)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3520)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2281)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:940)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at com.icdb.ICDBWebService.searchUsers(ICDBWebService.java:2209)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2540)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2990)
    ... 49 more
[ERROR] JDBC rollback failed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC rollback failed
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:200)
    at com.icdb.ICDBWebService.searchUsers(ICDBWebService.java:2252)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1198)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4690)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.rollback(NewProxyConnection.java:855)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:192)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 30,428,851 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3090)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2979)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3520)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2281)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:940)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at com.icdb.ICDBWebService.searchUsers(ICDBWebService.java:2209)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2540)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2990)
    ... 49 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would configure [connection testing](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing). c3p0 can check connection before handing it to your application.

Comment: Thanks. Found this link very usefull. I was missing that knowladge